# Datatable data not updating with new server data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, datatable

I'm using a datatable to show some data, and I have a date filter. I want to update my datatable according to new filtered data.

here is my datatable code:

```js
            window.emp_jobCount_datatable = $('#emp-jobCount-datatable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '/get_jobCount_datatable_data',
                columns: 
                    [
                      {
                        data: 'id', 
                        name: 'id'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'firstname', 
                        name: 'firstname'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'lastname', 
                        name: 'lastname'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'category', 
                        name: 'category',
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'count', 
                        name: 'count',
                      },
                    ],
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ]    
              })
```

here is my filter request:

```js
$(document).on('click','#filtenByMonth', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var date = $('#month-select').find(":selected").val(); 
    var filterDate = (+date + +1); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/emp_filterBy_month',
            data: 
            {
                date: filterDate
            }
        })
        .done(function(res) {
            window.emp_jobCount_datatable.rows.add(res.datatableJSON);
            window.emp_jobCount_datatable.clear().draw();
        })
        .fail(function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
    
});
```

I tried the below codes and nothing works for me,

```js
window.emp_jobCount_datatable.clear().draw();

// res.datatableJSON is new filtered JSON result
window.emp_jobCount_datatable.rows.add(res.datatableJSON).draw();
window.emp_jobCount_datatable.clear().draw();
```

How to properly update the datatale with new data. please help!!